# RecyclerView добавлять новые элементы и отсортировать их

Tags: android, recyclerview, adapter, position

Нужна очень ваша помощь,есть RecyclerView так же есть Flbutton,рандомна задаю числа P,и сортирую их от минимального к максимальному.
Все работает ,но при нажатии кнопки появляется новый item ,который должен опять от сортироваться от мин к макс.

Но как видно н скриншоте у меня не получается помогите реализовать ,что при добавлении нового itema он сортировался как изначалные.

Пример, изначально есть 3 itema,у которых 1P=1 2P=30 3P=2,он сортируеться и получается 1P=1 3P=2 2P=30,потом при нажатии на кнопку должен появиься новый item NewP=9,тогда получается 1P=1 3P=2 NewP=9 2P=30 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    public class OneFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    public OneFragment() {

    }

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    ArrayList<Processor> dataModels;
    private static ... adapter;
    FloatingActionButton button;
    int pos,temp,temp1,temp2;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
button=(android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton)view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        final int bundle = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getInt("P");

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        Random rnd = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        dataModels = new ArrayList<>();
//Рандомна задаю числа в масисв и вывожу их в Recycler
        final int[] arrayTitle = new int[bundle];
        final int[] arrayP = new int[bundle];
        final int[] arrayT = new int[bundle];
        final int[] arrayR = new int[bundle];
        for (int i = 0; i < bundle; i++) {
            int p = 1 + rnd.nextInt(10 - 1 + 1);
            int t = 6 + rnd.nextInt(22 - 6 + 1);
            int r = 100 + rnd.nextInt(1000 - 100 + 1);
            arrayTitle[i] = i;
            arrayP[i] = p;
            arrayT[i] = t;
            arrayR[i] = r;
        }
       //здесь сортирую их от мин к макс
        for(int i = 0; i< bundle; i++)
        {
            pos=i;
            for(int j = i+1; j< bundle; j++)
            {
                if(arrayP[j]<arrayP[pos])
                    pos=j;
            }

            temp=arrayP[i];
            arrayP[i]=arrayP[pos];
            arrayP[pos]=temp;

            temp1= arrayTitle[i];
            arrayTitle[i]= arrayTitle[pos];
            arrayTitle[pos]=temp1;

            temp2=arrayR[i];
            arrayR[i]=arrayR[pos];
            arrayR[pos]=temp2;

            dataModels.add(new Processor(String.valueOf(arrayTitle[i]), arrayP[i], arrayT[i], arrayR[i], arrayR[i]));

  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        // создаем адаптер
        adapter = new ProcessorAdapter(dataModels, getContext());
        final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
//здесь удаляю каждый Элемент отсортированный через 4 секунды
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                int max = 0;
                int iOfMax = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < arrayP.length; i++) {
                    if (arrayP[i]  < max) {
                        max = arrayP[i];
                        iOfMax = i;
                    }
                }

               dataModels.remove(iOfMax);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                if (dataModels.size() > 0)
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
            }
        }, 3000);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return view;
    }
//Здесь написал какой то бред ,но он добавляет эл и удаляет но не сортирует
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int newP=1;
        final int[] arrayTitle = new int[newP];
        final int[] arrayP = new int[newP];
        final int[] arrayT = new int[newP];
        final int[] arrayR = new int[newP];
        Random rnd = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        for (int i = 0; i < newP; i++) {
            int title = 10 + rnd.nextInt(20 - 1 + 1);
            int prioritett = 1 + rnd.nextInt(10 - 1 + 1);
            int timer = 6 + rnd.nextInt(22 - 6 + 1);
            int ramm = 100 + rnd.nextInt(1000 - 100 + 1);
            arrayTitle[i] = title;
            arrayP[i] = prioritett;
            arrayT[i] = timer;
            arrayR[i] = ramm;

                //dataModels.add(0, new Processor(String.valueOf(NewarrayTitle[i]), NewarrayP[i], NewarrayT[i], NewarrayR[i], NewarrayR[i]));

        }
        adapter = new ProcessorAdapter(dataModels, getContext());
        for(int i=0;i<newP;i++)
        {
            pos=i;
            for(int j=i+1;j<newP;j++)
            {
                if(arrayP[j]<arrayP[pos])
                    pos=j;
            }

            temp=arrayP[i];
            arrayP[i]=arrayP[pos];
            arrayP[pos]=temp;

            temp=arrayTitle[i];
            arrayTitle[i]=arrayTitle[pos];
            arrayTitle[pos]=temp;


            temp=arrayR[i];
            arrayR[i]=arrayR[pos];
            arrayR[pos]=temp;
            if(arrayP[])
            dataModels.add(new Processor(String.valueOf(arrayTitle[i]), arrayP[i], arrayT[i], arrayR[i], arrayR[i]));

        }
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

}
```

Если что то не понятно пишите объясню вопрос более лучше,очень нужна помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что то наделали вы много весьма странного. Проще написать как надо, чем объяснять, что не так.

Создаем модель данных. Используется тип `Integer`, так как он, в отличии от примитивного `int`, имеет интерфейс `Comparable`, который нам понадобится для сортировки:

```
public class Processor {
    private Integer title;
    private Integer prioritet;
    private Integer timer;
    private Integer ram;

    public Processor(int title, Integer prioritet, int timer, int ram) {
        this.title = title;
        this.prioritet = prioritet;
        this.timer = timer;
        this.ram = ram;
    }

    public Integer getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(Integer title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Integer getPrioritet() {
        return prioritet;
    }

    public void setPrioritet(Integer prioritet) {
        this.prioritet = prioritet;
    }

    public Integer getTimer() {
        return timer;
    }

    public void setTimer(Integer timer) {
        this.timer = timer;
    }

    public Integer getRam() {
        return ram;
    }

    public void setRam(Integer ram) {
        this.ram = ram;
    }
}
```

Из активити показываем фрагмент со списком и передаем туда начальное количество процессоров (6):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ListFragment fragment = new ListFragment();
        final Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("index", 6);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
    }
}
```

В фрагменте принимаем начальное количество, заполняем модель и отображаем ее в списке:

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    ArrayList dataModels;
    Random rnd;
    ProcessorAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final int index = getArguments().getInt("index", 0);
        rnd = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listfragment, container, false);
        final RecyclerView rv = view.findViewById(R.id.list);
        final Button addButton = view.findViewById(R.id.button);

        dataModels = new ArrayList<Processor>();


        for (int i = 0; i<index; i++){
            dataModels.add(getProcessor(i));
        }

        sortByPrioritet();

        addButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        adapter = new ProcessorAdapter(dataModels);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
        return view;
    }

    // метод сортирует коллекцию по приоритету (полю prioritet)
    private void sortByPrioritet() {
        Collections.sort(dataModels, new Comparator<Processor>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Processor o1, Processor o2) {
                return o1.getPrioritet().compareTo(o2.getPrioritet());
            }
        });
    }

    // метод генерирует новый процессор
    private Processor getProcessor(int i) {

        int p = 1 + rnd.nextInt(10 - 1 + 1);
        int t = 6 + rnd.nextInt(22 - 6 + 1);
        int r = 100 + rnd.nextInt(1000 - 100 + 1);
        return new Processor(i, p, t, r);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // добавляем еще один процессор, сортируем и обновляем список
        dataModels.add(getProcessor(3));
        sortByPrioritet();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Ну и адаптер на всякий случай:

```
public class ProcessorAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProcessorAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<Processor> mDataModels;

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView title,prioritet,timer,ram;
    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        title = view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        prioritet= view.findViewById(R.id.prioritet);
        timer =  view.findViewById(R.id.timer);
        ram =  view.findViewById(R.id.ram);
    }
}
    public ProcessorAdapter(ArrayList<Processor> dataset) {
        mDataModels = dataset;
    }
    @Override
    public ProcessorAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(view);
        return vh;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Processor processor = mDataModels.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(String.valueOf(processor.getTitle()));
        holder.prioritet.setText(String.valueOf(processor.getPrioritet()));
        holder.timer.setText(String.valueOf(processor.getTimer()));
        holder.ram.setText(String.valueOf(processor.getRam()));
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataModels.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, fragment).commit(); ,R.id.container здесь это что?

Comment: @fcbarcafc Это id контейнера (лэйаута) на разметке активити, куда будет помещен фрагмент (FrameLayout)

Comment: подскажите как мне получить все значения ram  и просуммировать их

Comment: как получить значение Ram и просуммировать их

Comment: @fcbarcafc Это совсем другая проблема. Создайте новый вопрос с вашей проблемой, в вопросе так же укажите ссылку на этот вопрос в качестве контекста проблемы.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/758310/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-ram-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D1%85

Comment: добавил вопрос посмотрите