# получить значение Ram и просуммировать их

Tags: android, recyclerview, adapter

Как получить значение Ram и просуммировать их?Нужно просуммировать значения ram которые уже рандомна получились в RecyclerView, при суммирование по чему то постоянно опять рандомные значения складываються , а мне надо которые уже есть в ReyclerView
Вот мой предыдущий вопрос
[RecyclerView добавлять новые элементы и отсортировать их](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/757381/recyclerview-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D1%85/757611?noredirect=1#comment1173121_757611)

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    ArrayList dataModels;
    Random rnd;
    ProcessorAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final int index = getArguments().getInt("index", 0);
        rnd = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listfragment, container, false);
        final RecyclerView rv = view.findViewById(R.id.list);
        final Button addButton = view.findViewById(R.id.button);

        dataModels = new ArrayList<Processor>();


        for (int i = 0; i<index; i++){
            dataModels.add(getProcessor(i));
        }

        sortByPrioritet();

        addButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        adapter = new ProcessorAdapter(dataModels);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
        return view;
    }

    // метод сортирует коллекцию по приоритету (полю prioritet)
    private void sortByPrioritet() {
        Collections.sort(dataModels, new Comparator<Processor>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Processor o1, Processor o2) {
                return o1.getPrioritet().compareTo(o2.getPrioritet());
            }
        });
    }

    // метод генерирует новый процессор
    private Processor getProcessor(int i) {

        int p = 1 + rnd.nextInt(10 - 1 + 1);
        int t = 6 + rnd.nextInt(22 - 6 + 1);
        int r = 100 + rnd.nextInt(1000 - 100 + 1);
        return new Processor(i, p, t, r);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // добавляем еще один процессор, сортируем и обновляем список
        dataModels.add(getProcessor(3));
        sortByPrioritet();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В ответе только относящийся к вопросу код. Сама реализация выводит сумму Ram в кнопку добавления нового процессора (для примера) и с каждым нажатием кнопки (добавлением процессора) обновляет значение:

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    ...
    Button addButton;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final RecyclerView rv = view.findViewById(R.id.list);
        addButton = view.findViewById(R.id.button);

        ...

        rv.setAdapter(adapter);

        ...

        addButton.setText(String.valueOf(getSumRam(dataModels)));
        return view;
    }

    private int getSumRam(ArrayList<Processor> processors){
            int sum = 0;
        for (Processor processor:processors){
            sum += processor.getRam();
        }
        return sum;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            dataModels.add(getProcessor(dataModels.size())); // очередной по порядку номер процессора
        sortByPrioritet();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        addButton.setText(String.valueOf(getSumRam(dataModels)));
    }
}
```